# woocommerce layout featured products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to customize the layout (html + css) of the featured products. In which folder the file is located? In the folder of my theme, I only have content-product_cat.php

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For CSS:** WooCommerce adds a class "featured" to the products that are featured.
In archives like shop or category page, you can use:

```
li.product.featured {
  /* CSS */
}
```

And in single page, you can use:

```
div.product.featured {
  /* CSS */
}
```

**For HTML**: You can edit **content-product.php** and **content-single-product.php** in your theme files and check if product is featured and make your changes. But you say your theme haven't those files, in regular way your theme has a folder "woocommerce". If it has, You can try copying these files from "plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php" and "plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php" to "themes/YOUR_THEME/woocommerce" and edit them.

I hope it helps...